# Find the the length x of the transmission line of \$100 \Omega\$ characteristic impedance

Tags: transmission-line

Find the the length x of the transmission line of \$100 \Omega\$ characteristic impedance where the load \$Z_L\$=\$100 + j 100 \Omega\$ becomes purely resistive. Also find \$R_x\$. Assume \$VSWR = 2.6 \$.

This problem I am trying to solve without using a smith's chart i.e. algebraically. A help with the formulae or the steps would be really kind.

Comment: Sounds like a homework question, sorry we don't do those for you.

Comment: Are we assuming a lossless line or...?

Comment: @KingDuken, lossless line. I wanted to ask, when the length is at where the load becomes purely resistive, is it the case always that input impedance is \$ VSWR * Z_0 \$